# computer stops responding to mouse clicks after opening visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

As of last week my computer stops responding to mouse clicks after I open Visual Studio 2013. I can still see the mouse cursor, and the mouse cursor is still moving, but when I click anywhere in the Visual Studio IDE or in any other application, nothing will happen. The mouse icon will also not change when hovering over links etc.
The problem will persist until I sign out. Then everything is back to normal until I open Visual Studio again.

Things I tried so far

- The mouse is fine, collegueas are experencing the same problem
- Rebooting
- I have upgraded from Update 4 to Update 5
- Going home for the weekend

We are using Windows Server 2012, no extensions installed for Visual Studio.

Comment: @Hunter Stevens I can find a lot of questions on StackOverflow about bugs in Visual Studio. They seem to be generally deemed acceptable and answered. I just consulted the Help Center "What topics can I ask about" and it mentions a.o. questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers".

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be resolved by killing a process called wisptis or by installing hotfix rollup 3026376 [as detailed here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/927119). Since googling did not easily bring this page up for me, this reference will hopefully help other people.